# Chrome removes space after 'to'

Tags: php, wordpress

Every time the word 'to' is used in a certain section of my site Chrome removes the space after it, conflated it with the previous word. I.e 'Committo volunteering regularly'

It is only happening within one of my bootstrap rows and doesn't happen in other browsers.

The page in question is: http://benefacto.org/fca/

I can't see any inconsistencies in the code compared with other sections.

Many thanks for your help

Comment: Opened in Chrome on Windows 10, and I can't find anywhere where the space is being removed.

Comment: Thanks Andy - I'm on a Mac.

Comment: I can't find anywhere that it says "Sign up to volunteer" with or without the space.

Comment: Apologies - it occurs on 'Committo volunteering regularly', 'Contributeto an FCA fundraising event' and 'Committo using the driers not paper' - I'm copying them straight out of Chrome

Comment: @Anant What browser ? Im not, I see space in html, Not on page

Comment: I think this is a problem with latest chrome mac version. I can replicate it.

Comment: I'm on a Mac running 10.11.5 and using Chrome Version 52.0.2743.116

Comment: @BenDarlington  you are right.coming in chrome only

Comment: @BenDarlington  those are static lines or you use php code to show those lines?

Comment: Does this issue occur if you are not using Bootstrap? Just vanilla HTML with no inline styles or CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know why, but seems that `word-wrap: break-word;` is your problem.

Try this

```
.h4-fca {
    word-wrap: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a very interesting problem. I too can see that first word after a 2 letter word gets concatenated. In order to solve it I replaced first space with `&nbsp;` but I don't really know the cause of it which I will look at.